# Do fishing cats attack domestic cats?

Tags: cats

I am living in a suburb of a South Asian country. I spotted a fishing cat in my backyard today night around 8.30 p.m. I have a two months old indoor/outdoor kitten in my house. I am worried whether this wild cat could attack my domestic pet kitten while she is outside.

This is the first time in my life I have seen any sort of wild cat in the are I live.

Can anyone please tell me whether these wild cats attack domestic cats?

Comment: one does not let an 8 weeks old kitten ouside at all unless you are with him/her.fishing cats do not come close to people and houses unless they are hungry.

Comment: Cats usually do not *eat* cats, as far as I can tell... I wonder what is going on in your area / country...

Comment: Cats generally won't *eat* other cats, true, but that doesn't mean they won't *harm* or *kill* other cats. The safest place for your cat is in the house.

Comment: well during the covid lockdowns a lot of animals came out from forests and used to hang around a lot in the areas where humans live. Many more animals like monkeys , wild bores, porcupines, komodo dragons, monitor lizards and even crocodiles in areas where water sources are, came out like this. And also my country is generally called a wild country with lot of animals so it's normal but wild cats have never been in the area before. Thank you anyway for responding, I prepared a cosy place for her inside and she is happily having a nap now.

Comment: In general - if you're there, wild animals tend not to attack humans. On the other hand, outdoors is *generally* dangerous. I live in a very urban area and we've had a community cat (very well socialised feral cat) get killed by a python. And at kitten size - there's a lot of hazards, ranging from birds of prey to snakes of various sorts

Comment: Be aware that fishing cats are a breed with so less number, that they are under safety measures worldwide. So any try to hurt or kill them, or damage their homes may (depending of the strictness of the official places) be punished. So you are a very rare human kind, to see a fishing cat in real live :) I am jalous...

Comment: Oh! so *fishing cat" is an actual distinct animal, not just an ordinary car that happens to fish... I learned something new today :)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishing_cat